# Optimization problem for maximum volume of inscribed figure.

Tags: geometry, optimization

While studying, I came upon  this problem: "What is the largest possible volume a right circular cylinder can have if it is inscribed in a sphere of radius 5?" The answer was shown as (500*pi)/(3*sqrt(3)). The explanation simply told me to find and substitute a volume equation, then use derivatives. I did not fully understand this problem with this short explanation. Could someone offer a detailed explanation to this problem?

Comment: It is a classical problem, and probably it has already been asked here on MSE. You may use derivatives or just the AM-GM inequality.